# How to normalize 360-degree videos so that certain object / person remains in the middle?

Tags: premiere, editing, 360video

I have multiple 360-degree clips recorded with Ricoh Theta S.

When recording I didn't think too much about orientation - where is back, where is front - it is 360-degree after all.

When editing and merging clips I realized that sometimes I'm located in in the front, in the back, on the side - it is very confusing experience.

**I need to "normalize" multiple clips - so that I'm in the middle.**

---

A proposed workflow (Premiere Pro):

- drag the clip to the timeline twice
- align them side by side so that I'm in the middle

It feels achievable, I'm just wondering if there is a better, recommended, default, sure-fire way?

---

**EDIT:** https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/VRSupport.html - I'm not sure if my version of Premiere Pro supports these workflows.

**PS:** This is a super-comprehensive link: http://jonnyelwyn.co.uk/film-and-video-editing/editing-360-and-vr-video/ *(very advanced, I just need basic stuff)*

Answer (score 2):

You may have sorted this out by now, but I saw the open question, so I thought I'd answer it.

If you have a subscription to the Adobe Creative Cloud, you can now do this reorientation in Premiere.  In June, Adobe bought out the Skybox plugin from Mettle.  Essentially, that plugin allows you to re-orient your 360 video in AE or PR among other things.

There's now an effect in Premiere called 'VR Projection' and it allows you to adjust the pan, tilt, and roll of your projection.